# Go to next visible cell without loop

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have an autofiltered table in Excel. I have to copy/paste values based on certain conditions and I also have to perform this on all visible cells in a particular column. I have written the code and it works well but the only thing is that it takes a lot of time as there are many rows. Can anyone please help me how to thrash time required? Here's the code. Thanks!

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()


Windows("Epson Itemcodes.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A" & i).Select
    Selection.Copy

Windows("Epson ASINs.xlsx").Activate
    Range("U1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(0, -12).Select


If ActiveCell.Value <> "Itemcode" Then

If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Else

    If ActiveCell.Value = Workbooks("Epson Itemcodes.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value Then
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Else
    ActiveCell.Value = "Conflct"

    End If
    End If

Else
Windows("Epson Itemcodes.xlsm").Activate
Range("I" & i).Value = "No match found"

End If

If ActiveCell.Value <> "Itemcode" Then


With ActiveSheet
Do

ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Activate
Do While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Activate
Loop

If ActiveCell.Value <> "Itemcode" Then

If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Else

    If ActiveCell.Value = Workbooks("Epson Itemcodes.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value Then
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Else

    ActiveCell.Value = "Conflct"

    End If
    End If

Else
Exit Do

End If

Loop
End With

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: My guess is that your code is not working. (In addition to not declaring variables, the value of `i` is never set and the first  statement would fail.) This site is for reviewing working code. You can find some extremely helpful tips on [using Option Explicit](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/3554/always-use-option-explicit#t=201612121340238925225), [avoiding SELECT](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=201612121340238925225), with other very useful tips.

Comment: Using a consistent indent for nested loops and Ifs will help a bunch also...

Answer (score 3):

Before you write another line of code, watch this [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&t=3112s&index=5).

Everyone here wants to help you but, and I know that you read this,  you have got to stop selecting and activating cells.  You also need to describe your data.  Posting screenshots wouldn't hurt either.  So if I sound mean but you wrote 72 lines of code to copy maybe 12 values.

`Range.Copy`, `Range.Cut`, `Range.Insert` and by default act on only the visible cells.

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()
    Dim Source As Range, Target As Range

    With Workbooks("Epson ASINs.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set Source = .Range("U2", .Range("U" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With

    With Workbooks("Epson Itemcodes.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set Target = .Range("U" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With

    Source.Offset(1).Copy Desination:=Target

End Sub
```